# Conversion to char from cell is not possible

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I'm trying to assign a sequence of randomly-generated numbers to a string array, but get the error:

```
Conversion to char from cell is not possible.

Error in work (line 11)
    first_gen(i) = num2cell(str_r);
```

I'm using a for loop to iterate through 10 times and hopefully fully populate my array, this is the trouble code:

```
first_gen = ['';'';'';'';'';'';'';'';'';''];

% our first generation of ants
for i = 1:10
    str_r = sprintf('%d',  randi([0,9],1,30));
    % modify selected characters.
    str_r(1:3:end) =  sprintf('%d',  randi([1,4],1,10));
    first_gen(i) = num2cell(str_r);
end
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I've tried using curly braces, like so:

`first_gen(i) = {num2cell(str_r)};`

But this just produces the same error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, your `first_gen` is a vector array, not a cell array. You cant store a cell in a vector. You need cell to store cells as bellow:

```
first_gen = cell(1,10);

% our first generation of ants
for i = 1:10
    str_r = sprintf('%d',  randi([0,9],1,30));
    % modify selected characters.
    str_r(1:3:end) =  sprintf('%d',  randi([1,4],1,10));
    first_gen{i} = num2cell(str_r);
end
```

The `first_gen` is then cell of cells:

```
first_gen = 

  Columns 1 through 8

    {1x30 cell}    {1x30 cell}    {1x30 cell}    {1x30 cell}    {1x30 cell}    {1x30 cell}    {1x30 cell}    {1x30 cell}

  Columns 9 through 10

    {1x30 cell}    {1x30 cell}
```